# when are objects released in objective-C program

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, autorelease

I am using the Big Nerd Ranch guide to get started on Objective C.  I have a question on the project talked about in chapter 20.  At a high level, the project does the following

1. Creates 3 classes Person, Employee (that inherits from person) and Assets (Employee has an instance variable that points to Assets object)
2. It then creates 2 NSMUtableARrays

   - Array 1: employees:  Array of Employee objects (some which point to 0 Asset objects, some to 1 and some to 2 asset objects)
   - Array 2: allAssets: Array os Asset objects (one entry for each Asset object created)
3. Following this, one of the objects in the employees array is released.  This results in this Employee object being deallocated, but the asset objects linked to the Employee object are not since allAssets array owns it
4. Following this, I put a sleep (60) before the return 0 in main

I see that if sleep(60) is after the @autoreleasepool{} then all objects get deallocated before the 1 minute of sleep happens

But if sleep(60) happens before the closing left brace, then all objects get de-allocated after the 1 minute of sleep happens

Why is this happening?  I thought autorelease would kick in only after return happens?  Why is it happening before the return in the case I put the sleep outside the @autorelease{}, is it just a compiler optimization that recognizes that objects are no longer needed at this point since the only line left is sleep()?

I have uploaded the project to

https://github.com/smartiothome/BMI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when control reaches the closing brace of the `@autorelease` pool, that is when the current pool is told to `drain`, which causes your objects to be deallocated. Your sleep call delays the `drain`.

To get a better idea of whats going on, I'd recommend you take a look at how `NSAutoreleasePool` worked before they added the new `@` syntax. That is essentially whats happening under the covers.

Comment: Note that app termination is a special situation where the autorelease pool may or not be drained.

Comment: Thanks, Nick, that is useful.  Zaph, could you elaborate on "App termination" is a special situation.  Does it mean that if app gets terminated unexpectedly, there are cases where it will cause some "zombie" memory to be left in the system (and reboot is the only option to clear everything up)?  Wont this cause the iOS device is guaranteed to be become very slow after some amount of use?

Comment: When an app exits by any means or path the OS will reclaim all resources including all memory obtained by the app. There will be no memory lost or zombies. All memory an app obtains it provided by the OS so it knows all memory to reclaim. This is one of the main function of the OS kernel. BTW: "resources" are much more than memory, it includes open files, streams, communications, any resource that is limited.

Comment: If you are interested there are several good books you can study or university courses you can take, un-official auditing is free — by unofficial I mean just attend, don't sign-up, graduate courses do not take role, I have never been asked to leave, I have attended courses that only had 8 students.

Comment: Thanks, Zaph.  Which books/courses do you recommend?

Answer (score 2):

Look at the sleep() [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sleep.1.html): "The sleep command suspends execution for a minimum of seconds."

Basically nothing is happening during sleep which is why it should never be used in a release program.

Also doing this at program exit is going to be undefined. The system is going to reclaim all memory wether the app releases it or not so the app may decide not to bother releasing anything on termination. Aside: One of the several things that the OS kernel does is handle resources, providing them to apps as request and making sure to reclaim all resources on normal app termination or by a crash.

You would be well advised to reformat the question *not* based on app shutdown and open a new question based on that.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is this happening? I thought autorelease would kick in only after
>   return happens?

When you `autorelease` an object, it will be `release`d when the current `@autoreleasepool` block (the innermost enclosing `@autoreleasepool` block in the call stack at runtime) ends.

If you do not have an `@autoreleasepool` block around your `autorelease` in the same function, then the "current `@autoreleasepool` block" is in a calling function further up the call frame, and therefore the `release` happens after return from the current function.

However, in this case, you do have an `@autoreleasepool` block around your `autorelease` in the same function, so the `release` happens at the end of that `@autoreleasepool` block.